Self duality of a connection is invariant under a gauge transformation
Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and let $P\to M$ be a (smooth) principal $G$-bundle over an oriented Riemannian smooth 4-manifold $(M,g)$. Let $E=P\times_{\text{Ad}}\mathfrak{g}$ be the adjoint bundle of $P$. The Hodge star operator $*_g:\Omega^2(M)\to \Omega^2(M)$ extends to $*_g:\Omega^2(M,E)\to \Omega^2(M,E)$ in a natural way.
Suppose $\omega\in \Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ is a connection 1-form on $P$, and let $\Omega\in \Omega^2(P,\mathfrak{g})$ be the curvature 2-form. The curvature 2-form is horizontal and $\textrm{Ad}$-equivariant, and via the canonical isomorphism $\Omega^2_{\text{Ad,hor}}(P,\mathfrak{g})\cong \Omega^2(M,E)$, $\Omega$ corresponds to an $E$-valued 2-form $\bar{\Omega}$ on $M$. Suppose that ${\Omega}$ is self-dual, i.e. $*_g\bar{\Omega}=\bar{\Omega}$.
Now let $\Theta:P\to P$ be a bundle automorphism; it is given by $\Theta(p)=p\cdot u(p)$ for some $G$-equivariant function $u:P\to G$. It is well-known that $\Theta^*\omega$ is also a connection 1-form and that its curvature 2-form is $\Theta^*\Omega$. I want to show that $\Theta^*\Omega$ is also self-dual, i.e. $*_g\overline{\Theta^*\Omega}=\overline{\Theta^*\Omega}$.
Let $\theta:E\to E$ be the vector bundle automorphism $[p,v]\mapsto [\Theta(p),v]$ induced by $\Theta$. Using the fact that $(\Theta^*\Omega)_p=\text{Ad}(u(p)^{-1})\circ \Omega_p$, I've shown that $\overline{\Theta^*\Omega}=\theta^{-1}\circ \bar{\Omega}$. So I am left to show that $*_g(\theta^{-1}\circ \bar{\Omega})=\theta^{-1}\circ \bar{\Omega}$. This would be done if $*_g$ commutes with $\theta$, but I'm not sure about this. Is it true?
P.S. Maybe there should be an additional assumption that the bundle $E$ has a fiberwise metric and that $\theta:E\to E $ is compatible with it.

Elements of $\Omega^2(M,E)$ are just sections of the vector bundle $E\otimes \wedge^2T^*M$. Your bundle morphism is really $\theta^{-1}\otimes \operatorname{id}_{\wedge^2T^*M}$ (well-defined since both factors are linear on fibres), while your extension of $\ast_g$ is really $\operatorname{id}_{E}\otimes \ast_g$ (again well-defined), and these clearly commute. More concretely, in a sufficiently small neighbourhood $U\subset M$, any $\alpha\in \Omega^2(M,E)$ can be written
$$
\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i\otimes\alpha_i
$$
where $\alpha_i\in\Omega^2(U)$, $e_i\in \Gamma(E\vert_U)$ are local basis sections of the restriction of $E$ over $U$ (i.e. $(e_1(x), \ldots, e_n(x))$ defines a basis of $E_x$ for every $x\in U$), and $n$ is the dimension of the fibres of $E$. Then
$\theta^{-1}(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^n\theta^{-1}(e_i)\otimes \alpha_i$ while $\ast_g\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^ne_i\otimes (\ast_g\alpha_i)$, which clearly commute.
Note, your definition of a bundle automorphism is usually called a vertical bundle automorphism, since it maps each fiber $P_x$ into itself. More generally, a bundle automorphism is any diffeomorphism $\Phi:P\to P$ satisfying the equivariance condition $\Phi(p\cdot g) = \Phi(p)\cdot g$. This then covers a diffeomorphism $\varphi:M\to M$ in the sense that the following diagram commutes
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
P @>\Phi>> P\\
@V \pi V V @VV \pi V\\
M @>>\varphi> M
\end{CD}
($\varphi = \operatorname{id}_M$ in your case). I haven't thought it through properly, but I imagine in order for the induced map to commute with $\ast_g$ in this more general case, $\varphi$ would need to be an isometry (or at least, this would be a sufficient condition).
